# Show Mysql data in Bar Chart in Java EE

Tags: jakarta-ee, bar-chart

I am very New to Data Analyses in Java EE I want show the mysql table data in Bar chat by using any API to draw graph write now i am getting the data from the database and show in the browser how can i populate that data in the Graph is there any simple way to show data in Graphs

Thanks in Advance......

Comment: Use [JFreechart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/)

Answer (score 0):

This may be (by far) not the simplest way to accomplish that. But since you mentioned Java EE, chances are good that you are using JSF for your frontend.

In that case, if you want bar charts that you can handle just like other JSF components and that integrate nicely with the rest of your UI, try [Primefaces charts](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/barChart.jsf). They also have a selection of other, more sophisticated charts you might find helpful

Comment: is there any sample example ?

Comment: @user1581386 - I have linked the official example in the answer. The source code in on the bottom of the page